# Find matching substrings in two lists

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have two lists: A and B. List lengths are not the same and they both contain strings. What is the best way to match substrings in both the lists?

```
list_A = ['hello','there','you','are']
list_B = ['say_hellaa','therefore','foursquare']
```

I would like a list of matching substrings called list_C which contains:

```
list_C = ['hell','there','are']
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095595/find-all-substrings-in-list-of-strings-and-create-a-new-list-of-matching-substri) answer, but it requires me to have a list of matching substrings. 
Is there a way I can get what I want without manually creating a list of matching substrings?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085069/pandas-find-super-string-in-one-series-from-another-series/51085122#51085122) also does not help me cause the second list contains substrings.

Comment: `Also suggest ways to implement` Probably not intentional, but when you write like this, it comes off as quite rude, makes people less inclined to help.

Comment: The most performant solution depends very much on how long the two lists are in relation to each other and how long the strings and patterns are on average.

Comment: @SuperStew Apologies, not intended.  Will edit it out.

Comment: A duplicate was asked 5 minutes earlier!

Comment: @schwobaseggl I actually have a pandas column of about 500,000 rows and there are about 100 unique strings in the column.

Comment: @sudnyank, Does the dup help you? If not, can you clarify why not?

Comment: @jpp It does not. Because the second list contains substrings of the original. I specifically asked for a way that does not require me to create a list of matching substrings.

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach. Using a `list comprehension`.

```
list_A = ['hello','there','you','are']
list_B = ['hell','is','here']
jVal = "|".join(list_A)        # hello|there|you|are

print([i for i in list_B if i in jVal ])
```

**Output:**

```
['hell', 'here']
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tag `pandas` solution from `str.contains`

```
#S_A=pd.Series(list_A)
#S_B=pd.Series(list_B)

S_B[S_B.apply(lambda x : S_A.str.contains(x)).any(1)]
Out[441]: 
0    hell
2    here
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC: I'd use Numpy

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

a = np.array(['hello', 'there', 'you', 'are', 'up', 'date'])
b = np.array(['hell', 'is', 'here', 'update'])

bina = b[np.where(find(a[:, None], b) > -1)[1]]
ainb = a[np.where(find(b, a[:, None]) > -1)[0]]

np.append(bina, ainb)

array(['hell', 'here', 'up', 'date'], dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: Any reason [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51085122/9209546) wouldn't work? (Feel free to reopen if you think there's a material difference in this question.)

Comment: Yeah, unless I misunderstood.  OP wanted a two way check.  Otherwise, I'm deleting.  Actually, I didn't do that right either.  Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_A = ['hello','there','you','are']
list_B = ['hell','is','here']
List_C = []

for a in list_A:
    for b in list_B:
        print(a,"<->",b)
        if a in b:
            List_C.append(a)
        if b in a:
            List_C.append(b)

print(List_C)
```

Comment: Please refrain from using offensive language in your posts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For funsies, here's an answer that uses regex!

```
import re

matches = []
for pat in list_B:
    matches.append(re.search(pat, ' '.join(list_A)))
matches = [mat.group() for mat in matches if mat]
print(matches)
# ['hell', 'here']
```

This returns a match object for each match that is found, the actual string of which is found by `match.group()`. Note that if no match is found (as is the case for the second element in your `list_B`), you get a `None` in `matches`, thus the need to add the `if mat` at the end of the list comprehension.